# shortest path going through m edges

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, directed-graph

Hello there smart people.

I have a following graph problem.

Given a complete, directed, wieghted graph with n vertices, find the length of the shortest path (starting at any vertex) going through m - 1 edges (edges in the path might repeat).
As for the limits n <= 200, m <= 1e9.

Looking at the limits I can say there must be some clever way without some sort of dp and graph traversing but I just cant think of anything like that.
Thanks in advance.

```
Example:
n = 3, m = 5

edges:
1 -> 2 weight = 10,
1 -> 3 weight = 100,
2 -> 1 weight = 10,
2 -> 3 weight = 50,
3 -> 1 weight = 30,
3 -> 2 weight = 70,

answer would be 40 (1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive solution would be to run BFS (breadth-first search) until the m<sup>th</sup> level and maintain the minimum sum of weights and return it.

---

But in the question it says we can include the vertex as many times till there is a path between them, so now we can do the below steps:

1. **Calculate all the cycles present in the graph**, we can reuse these cycles in calculating the minimum weight possible.

**for example:**

in the question, there is a cycle present `1-->2-->1` of length=3 weight=20, the value of m = 5, now we can use this path twice, but if m was 6 then we are left with 1 more node to include.

---

2. Now we can calculate the min path (to include leftover nodes) of length `l` (which is 1 if m=6) from `1` and add it to the above weight. (which will we 1-->2 =10)

---

3. **Repeat the steps 1 and 2** for every cycle present in the graph and maintain the minimum sum.

Below is the c++ code describing the above solution (it may not be 100% correct, but you will get the basic idea)

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Edge{
    int src, dest, weight;
};

struct Node{
    int start_vertex, end_vertex, weight, edge_count=0;
};

class Graph{
public: 
    vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> adjList;
    int V;

    Graph(vector<Edge> edges, int V){

        adjList.resize(V+1);
        this->V = V;

        for(Edge edge:edges){
            adjList[edge.src].push_back({edge.dest, edge.weight});
        }
    }
};

int BFS(Graph &g, int m){

    queue<Node> Q;

    vector<Node> cycles;

    // to store min path from vertex i of length j
    vector<vector<int>> dp(g.V+1, vector<int>(g.V+1, INT_MAX));

    for(int i=0; i<=g.V; i++)
        dp[i][0] = 0;

    for(int i=1; i<=g.V; i++){
        Q.push({i, i, 0, 1});
    }

    while(!Q.empty()){
        Node top = Q.front();

        Q.pop();

        if(top.edge_count >= g.V) break;

        int v = top.end_vertex;
        int start_vertex = top.start_vertex;
        int weight = top.weight;
        int edge_count = top.edge_count;

        for(auto x:g.adjList[v]){
            // finding all the cycles
            if(x.first == start_vertex){
                Node n = {start_vertex, v, weight+x.second, edge_count+1};
                cycles.push_back(n);
            }else{
                Q.push({start_vertex, x.first, weight+x.second, edge_count+1});
            }


            if(dp[start_vertex][edge_count] > weight+x.second){
                dp[start_vertex][edge_count] = weight+x.second;
            }
        }
    }

    // finding minimum:
    int min_weight = INT_MAX;

    if(m<=g.V){
        for(int i=1; i<=g.V; i++){
            min_weight = min(min_weight, dp[i][m]);
        }
    }

    // checking all the cycles for  reusability and maintaining min sum
    for(int i=0; i<cycles.size(); i++){

        int sum = cycles[i].weight;

        int length_left_to_cover = m-cycles[i].edge_count;

        sum += length_left_to_cover/(cycles[i].edge_count-1) * cycles[i].weight;

        int vertices_left_to_include = 0;

        if(m-cycles[i].edge_count>0){

            vertices_left_to_include = (m-cycles[i].edge_count)%(cycles[i].edge_count-1);

        }

        min_weight = min(min_weight, sum+dp[cycles[i].start_vertex][vertices_left_to_include]);
    }

    return min_weight;


}

// 1 -> 2 weight = 10,
// 1 -> 3 weight = 100,
// 2 -> 1 weight = 10,
// 2 -> 3 weight = 50,
// 3 -> 1 weight = 30,
// 3 -> 2 weight = 70,

int main(){
    vector<Edge> edges = {
        {1, 2, 10},
        {1, 3, 100},
        {2, 1, 10},
        {2, 3, 50},
        {3, 1, 30},
        {3, 2, 70}
    };

    int V = 3;
    int m = 5;

    Graph g(edges, V);

    cout<<"Min weight: "<<BFS(g, m);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Min weight: 40
```